# How to apply loading state only to particular component in livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel Livewire in my project, I use `wire:loading` for loading the state while clicking. I iterated all the tasks in foreach loop but the loading state applies for all components. Here is the code.

[image]

**Blade file**

GitLab: https://gitlab.com/tasklog/tasklog/-/blob/master/resources/views/livewire/home/tasks.blade.php

```html
<button type="button" wire:click="togglePraise({{ $task->id }}, {{ $task->user->id }})">
    
    <span class="small text-black-50 font-weight-bold">
        {{ $task->task_praise->count() }}
    </span>
    <div wire:loading wire:target="togglePraise">
        Processing...
    </div>
</button>
```

**Controller file**

GitLab: https://gitlab.com/tasklog/tasklog/-/blob/master/app/Http/Livewire/Home/Tasks.php

```php
public function togglePraise($id, $user_id)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->id === $user_id) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Forbidden!');

            return;
        }
        $isPraised = TaskPraise::where([
            ['user_id', Auth::user()->id],
            ['task_id', $id],
        ])->count();
        if ($isPraised === 1) {
            TaskPraise::where([
                ['user_id', Auth::user()->id],
                ['task_id', $id],
            ])->delete();

            return true;
        } else {
            TaskPraise::create([
                'task_id' => $id,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            ]);

            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return session()->flash('message', 'Forbidden!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Being able to scope loading targets to actions with parameters is coming soon!

Comment: same use case, same problem, any update?

Answer (score 4):

I know the question was before the realease of v2, yet adding the answer for v2 for reference.

as per the [Livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/loading-states#targeting-actions) if you're using v2, you may specify the action and its parameters in the wire:target directive. For your example, it would be like this:

```
wire:target="togglePraise({{ $task->id }}, {{ $task->user->id }})"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to do it by loading targets to actions with parameters so I used jquery with the livewire

Button in the table loop with default d-none loading icon class

```
  <div class="col-3">
    <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-save ">
     Save <span class="loading-icon d-none">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:14px"></i></span> 
 </button></div>
```

Javascript code to call livewire and enable loading

```
$('.btn-save').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.parameter-value').removeClass("error-field");
  var row  = $(this).closest('tr');
  row.find('.loading-icon').removeClass('d-none');
  var parameter = row.data('parameter');
  var value = $.trim(row.find('.parameter-value').val())
  if(value == ""){
     row.find('.parameter-value').addClass('error-field');
   }else{
     row.find('.parameter-value').removeClass('error-field');
    //Livewire call
    @this.addParameterValue(parameter,value);
   }
});
```

before LiveWire function ends dispatch browser event

```
public function addParameterValue($parameterID,$value)
{
    ...
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('parameter_value-saved');
}
```

Handle Browser event from javascript end and remove hide loading icon inside

```
 window.addEventListener('parameter_value-saved', event => {
     $('.loading-icon').addClass('d-none');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. After researching, I decided to make 2 `wire:click`, IDK if this is the best way to solve this but yeah that's what I do

```
<div wire:loading wire:target="LoadingAnimation({{$loop->iteration}})">
   // icon loading or teks for showing this row load sth
</div>

......

<div wire:click="LoadingAnimation({{$loop->iteration}})">
   <a wire:click="setUpdateid({{$author->id}})">
     // your content here , teks or maybe an icon
   </a>
</div>
```

If you have any questions let me know, Happy coding!

Edit: Don't forget to make the method inside the class, like the `LoadingAnimation` and the `setUpdateid`